# Automatically inserting additional columns in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql, database, automation, pivot-table

Say I have a table like so

```
+----+----------+------+
| id |   name   | type |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | apple    | F    |
|  1 | pear     | F    |
|  1 | cucumber | V    |
|  2 | orange   | F    |
|  2 | grass    | NULL |
|  2 | broccoli | V    |
|  3 | flower   | NULL |
|  3 | tomato   | NULL |
+----+----------+------+
```

I want to end up with a table that counts the number of elements for each type (including NULL types) AND for each id, like this:

```
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | type_NULL_count | type_F_count | type_V_count |
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |               0 |            2 |            1 |
|  2 |               1 |            1 |            1 |
|  3 |               2 |            0 |            0 |
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

This is rather easy to do, but is there a way (a query I can write or something else) such that when I go back and edit one of the type fields in the first table, I end up with a properly updated count table?

For example, let's say I want to add a new type (type `X`) and change the `type` field for `flower` from `NULL` to `X`. Is there a way to end up with the following table without having to rewrite the query or add more statements?

```
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | type_NULL_count | type_F_count | type_V_count | type_X_count |
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |               0 |            2 |            1 |            0 |
|  2 |               1 |            1 |            1 |            0 |
|  3 |               1 |            0 |            0 |            1 |
+----+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, so I am open to suggestions

Comment: Which version of mySQL do you use?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: What you want is a "dynamic pivot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a secondary table which it's number of columns changes based on your first table is not a viable option.
Do you need to keep the result in a table or it will be displayed as a report?

I think a better way to do this is using the SQL below calculate counts by id plus type and display using your data display tool the way you like it.

```
select id, type, count(*) count
from d
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

The output would be

```
id  type    count
1   F   2
1   V   1
2   F   1
2   V   1
2       1
3   X   1
3       1
```